# Rails create new record without redirect instead refresh and stay on current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following form, also I'm doing `CollectionPageImage.new` because its creating new record from another model.

```
= simple_form_for(Spree::CollectionPageImage.new, :url => admin_collection_page_images_url, :html => { :multipart => true, }) do |f|
  = render :partial => 'spree/shared/error_messages', :locals => { :target => @collecion_page_images }
  = f.input :image, :label => "Collection images: "
  = f.association :collection_page
  = @collection_page.title
  = submit_tag t("create")
```

After it is created it is currently forwarding to admin_collection_page_images_url or /collection_page_images

I would like it to simply refresh and stay on the current page after each record is created, is there a quick way accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a `create` action of your controller that looks kind of like this:

```
def create
  @collection_page_image = CollectionPageImage.new(collection_page_image_params)

  if @collection_page_image.save
    # Here, redirect to the edit page of the just-created record
    redirect_to admin_collection_page_image_url(@collection_page_image)
  else
    flash[:errors] = @collection_page_image.errors
    redirect_to action: :new
  end
end
```

Notice the `redirect_to` instruction if the `.save` is successfull on the record.

Comment: thank you so much, I just changed it to `redirect_to :back` and it works nicely, should definitely use some JS next time though.